Will off-gassing of a decomposing astronaut corpse burst the space-suit?
In astronaut Chris Hadfields’s novel “The Apollo Murders”, a deceased astronaut on a hypothetical Apollo 18 mission rapidly becomes a disposal problem. Post-mortem off-gassing threatens to burst the Russian spacesuit his corpse is being stored in during transit to the Moon. According to the plot, this would fill the spacecraft with intolerably putrid gasses.
The rapidity of odiferous gas production seems unrealistic.
According to https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC10538644

The odor profile associated with decomposition consists of a range of
volatile organic compounds (VOCs) … There are few articles on the
profile of VOCs released during the decomposition of the body. …
cadaverine and putrescine are primarily responsible for the distinct
smell of death, but they are not volatile organic compounds.
Decomposition ...
typically commences, on average, 4 minutes after death …
categorization of the decomposition process consists of five stages:
fresh, bloated, active, advanced, and dry… the ‘bloat’ stage lasts
from three to seven ... days after death… Active decay begins
between seven and ten days and lasts approximately until 20 days.

There is no provision for storage of deceased crew, even in ISS. What to do until the hearse arrives: is there a designated morgue on ISS? .
Is the urgency portrayed in Hadfield’s book realistic?

I gave up on the book after the endless explanation of how the collective works in a helicopter.

@OrganicMarble ... classic example of a picture being worth a thousand words.

It's a fiction book with a bit of a sci-fi flavor. Fiction authors are allowed to abuse the truth, so long as the abuse isn't overly egregious.  Note: I have not read the book, but I have seen very bloated dead cows, so this does not seem that egregious at all.

A space suit should be equipped with a pressure relief valve. So the suit pressure will never reach the burst pressure.
